# Simple question about java SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

**This will probably be a dumb question, but I don't understand the java date function. Here is some code:**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
Date s = sdf.parse(var);
Calendar scal = java.util.GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
scal.setTime(s);   
Log.w("Time: ", Long.toString(s.getTime()));
```

If var = "10:00" I get "64800000".

If var = "11:00" I get "68400000".

If var = "12:00" I get "28800000".

If var = "13:00" I get "75600000".

If var = "14:00" I get "79200000".

If var = "00:00" I get "28800000".

What is up with 12:00? Why, when var=12:00 do I get the same result as when it's 00:00? All the other results seem correct. I obviously don't understand the java date function, but I can't seem to find any explanation for this anywhere. This is screwing up my time span calculator.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Where are you setting var? Since you are using hh:mm that is non military time - so perhaps that's why you are getting 00 for 12.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to use 24-hour time, you need to use the capital HH format:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

I should have used "H" instead of "h". "h" is for am/pm format.